# How to get only the posts posted by the Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API v2.4 and I want to get all the photos created by my app on a page.

I use the following url:

```
[pageid]/photos?fields=link,created_time,name&type=uploaded&limit=25
```

How do I filter the photos so that I can only see the photos posted by my app?

Comment: The API doesn’t currently offer that – so you’ll need to do that filtering on your end.